# DataGridView won't show data -System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show the data from datagridview in the textboxes near it when I select a certain field. But whenever I click on a field containing info I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection'. If you need more code or a screenshot of the form or error, I will provide it.

```
private void PregledKorisnika_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     UnameTB.Text = PregledKorisnika.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     UfullnameTB.Text = PregledKorisnika.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     UpasswordTB.Text = PregledKorisnika.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     UphoneTB.Text = PregledKorisnika.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
 }
```

```
    con.Open();
    string myquery = "select * from UserTable";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myquery, con);                 
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    var ds = new DataSet();    
    da.Fill(ds);
    PregledKorisnika.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Does the grid have a `DataSource`? If it does, then you may want to look at setting each textboxes "DataBindings." ... something like... `textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", GridDataSource, "ColumnPropertyName");`

Comment: @JohnG I guess it does im not sure? Is this it? I dont know much about C# im following a tutorial online, im doing it as a school project. 

               `con.Open(); 
                string myquery = "select * from UserTable";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myquery, con);
                SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                PregledKorisnika.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                con.Close(); `
Idk know how to format lmao sry

Comment: You should "Edit" your question and add the code from your comment. Do not add the code as a comment it belongs in the question. If the code in the previous comment works, then I suggest you bind the text boxes as I described previously. If you bind each text box to a particular column in the grids data source, then the code in the grids `CellContentClick` event will be unnecessary.

Comment: Alright I'll try googling around to try and do that